# Weird Generics Behaviour with Interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, extends, implements

I want to create a generic class that takes elements of some generic type that are comparable. So I do:

`public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>>`

and inside the class `Foo` I have things like:

`public void bar(T t)`

and I'm assured that I can write code like this: `t.compareTo(v)`.

*Question 1:* Why when using generics we have `extends` instead of `implements` for an interface? `Comparable` is not a class.

\\

Assume now that I want to create another similar class to the above also implementing
the `bar` method. I thought of creating this interface:

```
public interface Face<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public void bar(T t);
}
```

and then I change class `Foo` to implement `Face` (`public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Face`).

*Question 2:* When doing this I get the following compile error:

**The method bar(T) of type Foo must override or implement a supertype method**.

Why is this?

When I tell Eclipse to `add the unimplemented methods` I get:
`public void bar(Comparable t)` instead of `... bar(T t)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Can't speak for the designers of Java generics, but presumably they did this to simplify the language.  The point of an `X extends Y` constraint is that we want to specify that `X` is assignable to type `Y` - in the end it's immaterial whether `Y` is an interface or a class, so making you use `implements` or `extends` based on whether `Y` is the one or the other seems like a hassle.
2. Try: `public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Face<T>` - Face is an interface with a type parameter, so you need to fill in that type parameter when extending the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Please re-format your question a bit. But if I understood anything there, do this:

```
// Face<T>, not just Face
public class Foo<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Face<T> {
}
```